# How to allow only specific files *.py, *.json, *.sh inside a git directory/nested subdirectories?

Tags: git

In my git repo, I've a directory which may contain nested subdirectories. I'd like to allow only *.py, *.sh and *.json in these nested subdirectories.

I tried adding the following to .gitignore:

```
/trials/*
!/trials/README
/experimental/**/
!/trials/**/*.py
!/trials/**/*.sh
```

But it doesn't allow to me to add something like trials/foo/bar.py.

Answer (score 3):

Once a folder is ignored, you cannot exclude files.
In other words:

**[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309)**.

The right way is exclude files from gitignore rules is by whitelisting folders first:

```
/trials/*
!/trials/**/
```

Then you can exclude files (in the same `.gitignore` file):

```
!/trials/**/*.py
!/trials/**/*.sh
```

Use also `git check-ignore -v -- afile` to see what gitignore rule applies for a given file.

Comment: Is the leading slash OK?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The leading slash will anchor the rule to the top folder of the Git repo. That seems what the OP wants when it comes to the trials folder.

Comment: OK.  Makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `!/trials/**/.py` to `!/trials/**/*.py`:

```
...
!/trials/**/*.py
!/trials/**/*.sh
```